# error: use of undeclared identifier 'AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer' (Android NDK)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm getting these undefined errors for NDK functions:

```
 In file included from /home/user/orwell2/myapp_flutter_app/android/app/src/main/cpp/MediaCodecDecoder.cpp:5:
  /home/user/myapp3/myapp_flutter/android/app/src/main/cpp/MediaCodecDecodedFrame.h:24:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer'
                  AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer(aMediaCodec, outputBufferIndex, false);
                  ^
  /home/user/myapp3/myapp_flutter/android/app/src/main/cpp/MediaCodecDecoder.cpp:31:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AMediaFormat_new'; did you mean 'AMediaFormat'?
          format.reset(AMediaFormat_new());
                       ^
  /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/media/NdkMediaFormat.h:47:29: note: 'AMediaFormat' declared here
  typedef struct AMediaFormat AMediaFormat;
                              ^
```

But I included its headers:

```
#include "media/NdkMediaFormat.h"
#include "media/NdkMediaMuxer.h"
#include "media/NdkMediaCodec.h"
#include "media/NdkMediaExtractor.h"
```

and I got no include errors. I'm building on Android Studio. It worked before, now it won't. I have no idea what might be causing this.

I also tried

```
#include <NdkImage.h>
#include <NdkImageReader.h>
#include <NdkMediaCodec.h>
#include <NdkMediaCrypto.h>
#include <NdkMediaDrm.h>
#include <NdkMediaError.h>
#include <NdkMediaExtractor.h>
#include <NdkMediaFormat.h>
#include <NdkMediaMuxer.h>
```

like it says here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/media but it didn't work.

My NDK version is `21.3.6528147` and

```
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 28
```

I also tried ndk `21.1.6352462`

Answer (score 0):

Solution: raise minimum sdk version to 21 because that's where those functions got inserted

```
    minSdkVersion 21
```